# How to pass parameters while using the async pipe in Angular/rxjs?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to use the declarative approach in Angular, unwrapping observables with the `async` pipe and using `OnPush` change detection.

I have a second observable, which may or may not be invoked, and needs data from the first observable to complete.

**order.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="order$ | async as order">
    <h3> Order {{ order.id }} </h3>
    ....
     
    <app-returns *ngIf="order.status === 'Returned'"
        [rma]="rma$ | async" >
    </app-returns>

</div>
```

**order.component.ts**

```
order$: Observable<Order> = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
   map((params: ParmaMap) => +params.get('id')),
   switchMap((id: number) => 
       this.orderSvc.get(id)
));

rma$: Observable<Rma> = this.order$.pipe(
    switchMap((order: Order) => 
        this.rmaSvc.get(order.rma.id)
));
```

This issue with this approach is that the Order service makes two calls to the API to complete this.

When I have multiple observables needed in the template, I'll usually use a `forkJoin` or `combineLatest` to combine them.  But in this case I only want to call the rma service if necessary.

Other, more naive approaches (while illustrating the issue well) have hilarious outcomes.  Can you say 429?

```
 <app-returns *ngIf="order.status === 'Returned'"
    [rma]="rma$(order.rma.id) | async" >
 </app-returns>
```

Typescript

```
rma$(id: number): Observable<Rma> {
    return this.rmaSvc.get(id);
}
```

How do I pass a parameter while using the async pipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change your order observable using **shareReplay** for caching to :

```
order$: Observable<Order> = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
   map((params: ParmaMap) => +params.get('id')),
   switchMap((id: number) => 
       this.orderSvc.get(id)
   ),
   shareReplay(1)
);
```

and then create your rma observable using switchMap

```
rma$: Observable<Rma> = order$.pipe(
  switchMap((order: Order) => 
    this.rmaSvc.get(order.rma.id)
)
```

Comment: Fits the bill- clean, declarative approach and only hits the API once.  Thanks!